# Is "contact address" on etherscan.io 100% trustable?

Tags: etherscan, trust

Let's say I want to know if the token OMG or TRX is compatible with myetherwallet, metamask, and other ERC-20 compatible wallets. I go to the website https://etherscan.io/ and search for it, and I see their logo, number of token holders, number of transfers and so on.

Is the information shown here 100% trustable? Is it automatic, or is it manually handled? I'm guessing that number of transfers is automatic, but the "Contact Address", is that always correct? Can anyone change it?

Comment: Do you mean "contract address?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EtherScan is a website, so in that sense, it's no more and no less trustable than any other website. While I believe the people who run Etherscan would never knowingly alter the data, that doesn't mean it cannot happen. If you want perfectly safe data about ERC20 tokens, the only truly secure source is the node itself, but then you would have the arduous task of getting the data off the blockchain. EtherScan itself is off-chain, and therefore not perfectly secure.